# File context menu contains Windows Defender, not Microsoft Defender

Tags: windows-defender, microsoft-defender

When I right-click on a file in the Windows Explorer to perform an on-demand scan of a single file, the context menu (shown below) presents me with *Windows* Defender, not *Microsoft* Defender.  My understanding is that this is the legacy Windows antivirus (AV).

My notifications refers to both Windows Defender and Microsoft Defender (shown below).  However, Windows Security shows only Microsoft Defender (shown below)

When I actually initiate the on-demand scan, I don't get a modern GUI showing the absence of threats.  Instead, a DOS window pops up and says "Signature update started" for the longest time (several minutes) before saying "No threats" (shown below).

Is this in fact the right AV?  If not, how do I get rid of it and get the right AV in the file context menu?  I am on Windows 10.

[image]

**Diagnostic efforts**

Thank you to DrMoishe Pippik for his prompting.

From `Start->Settings->System->About`, my OS versions is "Windows 10 Pro", version 21H2, OS build 19044.2604, "Experience" "Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0". I don't know what those dot numbers refer to, but I update and reboot whenever I am prompted to.

I looked at [SFC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e).  It requires DISM, On which I found intro's [here](https://www.techtarget.com/searchenterprisedesktop/definition/Microsoft-Windows-Deployment-Image-Servicing-and-Management-DISM) and [here](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/difference-between-sfc-chkdsk-and-dism.html).  After completing the DISM and SFC, the final message was:

> Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.  For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.

Nothing was changed by this, unfortunately, even after a reboot.

Comment: **What version of Windows**? Have you performed all updates? Used SFC and DISM to check and repair OS errors?

Comment: Thanks, DrMoishe Pippik.  In response to your question and suggestion, I added the details to the posted question.

Comment: As you stated, that is *not* the normal operation nor appearance  of a Windows 10, 21H2 context menu for *Microsoft* Defender. Have you had other antimalware products installed? Consider downloading a stand-alone anti-virus scanner (https://www.geckoandfly.com/9751/free-portable-antivirus-software-microsoft-safety-scanner/) to check for issues (e.g., malware masquerading as AV). Also consider downloading the Windows 10 ISO to USB with the media creation tool, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10, and reinstalling, keeping files. If you do so **make a disk image first**.

Comment: OK, thanks again.  That would be another weekend excursion for me, and I'll have to find a weekend to do this.  In the meantime, it seems that I can invoke on-demand scans on selected files via `Windows Security -> Scan options -> Custom scan`.

Comment: **Windows Defender** is the current name of the client security tool published by Microsoft.

**Microsoft Defender** is the current name of the enterprise-class security suite by Microsoft. One portion of this security suite is "Microsoft Defender for Endpoint", which is the client security tool analogous to Windows Defender, but which is managed and controlled by the upstream management tools of that suite. 

So, the name does indicate you have the correct product version, but it is clearly broken in some way.